# Finetuned YOLOv8 Classifier generates error during prediction

Tags: python, yolo, transfer-learning, yolov8

I fine-tuned a YOLOv8 model on a roboflow dataset (task: classify). I downloaded the best parameters and tried using them for prediction using the following code:

```
model2 = YOLO("spectrogramfinetunedyolo.pt")
result = model2("640_X_640.jpg")
```

I keep on receiving the following error and I don't know what went wrong. I tried changing the file type and I tried with different image sizes but the error persists.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 4
      1 model2 = YOLO("spectrogramfinetunedyolo.pt")
      2 # results = model(['s1Voicespectro/'+ i for i in os.listdir('s1Voicespectro')])
      3 # result = model2("640_X_640.jpg")
----> 4 model2.predict("640_X_640.jpg")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:239, in Model.predict(self, source, stream, predictor, **kwargs)
    237 if prompts and hasattr(self.predictor, 'set_prompts'):  # for SAM-type models
    238     self.predictor.set_prompts(prompts)
--> 239 return self.predictor.predict_cli(source=source) if is_cli else self.predictor(source=source, stream=stream)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py:198, in BasePredictor.__call__(self, source, model, stream, *args, **kwargs)
    196     return self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs)
    197 else:
--> 198     return list(self.stream_inference(source, model, *args, **kwargs))

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py:35, in _wrap_generator.<locals>.generator_context(*args, **kwargs)
     32 try:
     33     # Issuing `None` to a generator fires it up
     34     with ctx_factory():
---> 35         response = gen.send(None)
     37     while True:
     38         try:
     39             # Forward the response to our caller and get its next request

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py:261, in BasePredictor.stream_inference(self, source, model, *args, **kwargs)
    259 # Preprocess
    260 with profilers[0]:
--> 261     im = self.preprocess(im0s)
    263 # Inference
    264 with profilers[1]:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\classify\predict.py:36, in ClassificationPredictor.preprocess(self, img)
     34 """Converts input image to model-compatible data type."""
     35 if not isinstance(img, torch.Tensor):
---> 36     img = torch.stack([self.transforms(im) for im in img], dim=0)
     37 img = (img if isinstance(img, torch.Tensor) else torch.from_numpy(img)).to(self.model.device)
     38 return img.half() if self.model.fp16 else img.float()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\classify\predict.py:36, in <listcomp>(.0)
     34 """Converts input image to model-compatible data type."""
     35 if not isinstance(img, torch.Tensor):
---> 36     img = torch.stack([self.transforms(im) for im in img], dim=0)
     37 img = (img if isinstance(img, torch.Tensor) else torch.from_numpy(img)).to(self.model.device)
     38 return img.half() if self.model.fp16 else img.float()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py:95, in Compose.__call__(self, img)
     93 def __call__(self, img):
     94     for t in self.transforms:
---> 95         img = t(img)
     96     return img

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py:361, in Resize.forward(self, img)
    353 def forward(self, img):
    354     """
    355     Args:
    356         img (PIL Image or Tensor): Image to be scaled.
   (...)
    359         PIL Image or Tensor: Rescaled image.
    360     """
--> 361     return F.resize(img, self.size, self.interpolation, self.max_size, self.antialias)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py:476, in resize(img, size, interpolation, max_size, antialias)
    470     if max_size is not None and len(size) != 1:
    471         raise ValueError(
    472             "max_size should only be passed if size specifies the length of the smaller edge, "
    473             "i.e. size should be an int or a sequence of length 1 in torchscript mode."
    474         )
--> 476 _, image_height, image_width = get_dimensions(img)
    477 if isinstance(size, int):
    478     size = [size]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py:78, in get_dimensions(img)
     75 if isinstance(img, torch.Tensor):
     76     return F_t.get_dimensions(img)
---> 78 return F_pil.get_dimensions(img)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\_functional_pil.py:31, in get_dimensions(img)
     29     width, height = img.size
     30     return [channels, height, width]
---> 31 raise TypeError(f"Unexpected type {type(img)}")

TypeError: Unexpected type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Roboflow did some preprocessing tasks, like resize (based on the error):

```
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py:361, in Resize.forward(self, img)
    353 def forward(self, img):
    354     """
    355     Args:
    356         img (PIL Image or Tensor): Image to be scaled.
   (...)
    359         PIL Image or Tensor: Rescaled image.
    360     """
--> 361     return F.resize(img, self.size, self.interpolation, self.max_size, self.antialias)
```

As you can see, it needs a PIL Image or Tensor. Simply use the Pillow module (pip install Pillow) to load image directly as a PIL Image.

```
from PIL import Image

image_path = "640_X_640.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)

result = model2(image)
```